# Map Dynamic json object to java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am building a REST API with a payload that has a property called jsonContent, which holds any valid json.

```
{
  "name":"foo",
  "jsonContent":{ "abc":"My content"}
}
```

On the server side I want to map the it to a generic java object ,and eventually save the whole object to mongodb

```
private String name;
private ?????? jsonContent
```

I am using jackson for mapping json to java.  How do I declare my java object so any json content can be used.

Comment: Any json can be represented in terms of maps (String to Object) and lists. I realise it won't work with Jackson, but you could parse the json into a series of maps and lists and then serialize those.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`JsonNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html):

```
private JsonNode jsonContent;
```

Comment: It works but when the object is saved to mongodb it is deserialized as follows with extra properties and nesting                 
       ` {"_class" : "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode",
        "_children" : {
            "title" : {
                "_value" : "Mytitle",
                "_class" : "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TextNode"
            }
        },
        "_nodeFactory" : {
            "_cfgBigDecimalExact" : false
        }`

Answer (score 1):

I answer my own question, Following worked just fine for me

```
private Map<String,Object> jsonContent;
```